# Bounty button on mobile looks as if it's already rewarded on question with open bounties

Tags: bug, design

I have [a question](https://askubuntu.com/q/173094/) with two answers, that I had an open bounty on.

When I opened the site on mobile to award the bounty before time runs out, the `+100` buttons looked as if the bounty was already awarded to both answers.
However, on the desktop version of the website, the buttons aren't so opaque and seem to have a bit of transparency to distinguish them from an already awarded bounty.

I think on the mobile site the buttons should also have a bit transparency to signify a difference between an already awarded bounty, and bounty which is yet to be awarded.

OS: Android 7.1.1
Browser: Firefox 54.0b8 & Chrome 58

Screenshots:

- [First Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1vbP.png)
- [Second Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Rl7.png)

Comment: Are you certain they *haven't* been rewarded?

Comment: @ThomasWard Yup. The screenshots I took were before I awarded the bounty. If you open the question now, you can see only one of the answers has been awarded a bounty, while the screenshots show both answers have one (which is because the bounty wasn't awarded yet) https://askubuntu.com/q/173094

Comment: link to both questions please, so we can compare what we actually see to your screenshots?

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm not sure I know how to fix my English better than this, but I hope this makes things a bit clearer. (All my life, I thought opaque meant transparent, until now lol.)